# how to set insert string values in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query in sql server

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),@X NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @X = 'val1,val2'

 SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [Persons] VALUES (' + @X + ')' 

 print (@SQL)
 exec (@SQL)
```

But i don't know how to set `@x` value by the right way ?

Comment: Are 'Val1' and 'Val2' string / `varchar` fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add escaped quotes:

```
SET @X = '''val1'',''val2'''
```

To make `@X` contain `'val1','val2'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to `DECLARE` every parameter.

```
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @X NVARCHAR(MAX)

     SET @X = '''val1'',''val2'''

     SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [Persons] VALUES (' + @X + ')' 

     print (@SQL)
     exec (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29969)</kbd>.

If `Val1` and `Val2` are string fields, you have to escape single quotes around string values as follows.

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @X NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @X = '''val1'',''val2'''

 SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [Persons] VALUES (' + @X + ')' 

 print (@SQL)
 exec (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

see from this link use split function,
[How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

then

```
Declare @ColNames VARCHAR(1000)='val1,val2'

INSERT INTO [Persons]
select item from dbo.SplitString(@ColNames,',')
```